# how to define HFPERCLK using HFRCO in I2C EFR32FG14

Tags: embedded

from page 280 of the manual HFRCO goes from 1Mhz to 38Mhz.
In the diagram shown bellow i only saw HFPERCLK usart.
the is no HFPERCLK I2C.

If we go from the starts then using CMU_HFCLKSEL value 1 we select HFRCO.
then using CMU_HFPRESC we define the prescale.and we enable It as I2C using 11.5.27 bitfield 8.
But as you can see in the diagram its our frequency goes threw the prescaling twice.

So is it realy doing twice the prescaling for every prescaling value we put?

Thanks.

https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efr32xg14-rm.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well what is the frequency of the HFRCO if it can be between 1 and 38 MHz?

Comment: Hello Justme,You are correct i only see a rangle in page 281 there are only names of the clocks on the left.
Where is the exact numbers of the clocks before they go in this prescale diagram?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first prescaler defines the internal high frequency clock (HFCLK) and the second prescaler defines the high speed peripheral clock (HFPERCLK) which is distributed to *all* peripherals in the high frequency domain.

The individual peripherals *also* have a prescaler so they can operate at a lower frequency if desired.

The I2C module has a simple clock divider register at offset 0x10 (see page 511 in the reference manual).

To generate a 100kHz clock (standard speed) from a 4MHz HFPERCLK you would need to divide by 40 and to achieve that you would need to write 39 decimal (0x27) into this register.

Comment: Hello ,How did you saw that HFPERCLK is 4MHz?
we need to pass threw two prescalers and choop a clock to divide.
Could you please show an example,What clock should i choose and what to prescale values to use in order to get HFPERCLK 4MHz?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't agree with the divider of 39 or 40 is correct, because it does not match the given formula of calculating Fscl from HFPERFCLK. Nlow and Nhigh are both 4.

Comment: Hello Justme,How can i see that HFPERCLK is 4MHz?
Thanks.

Comment: @rocko445 If you can use UART for serial comms, and have set the baud rate by assuming the HFPERCLK is 4 MHz, then it is 4 MHz.